# python: best way to verify conditions and raise Exception

Tags: python, exception, if-statement

hi
i have to verify if a vector contains all 0 or 1 and if not raise exception:

```
def assert_all_zero_or_one(vector):
    if set(vector)=={0}: return 0
    if set(vector)=={1}: return 1
    raise TypeError
```

with this exceution

```
assert_all_zero_or_one([1,1,1]) # return 1
assert_all_zero_or_one([0,0]) # return 0
assert_all_zero_or_one([1,0,1]) # raise TypeError
```

i don't like this solution.. there is a best way to do it with python?

Comment: *i don't like the if falls* what does this mean?

Comment: Why are you returning 0 or 1?  Why not `False` and `True`?

Comment: @felix: sorry english is not my first lang. "if falls" means that i don't like if after if after if etc..

Comment: And `assert_all_zero_or_one([2,2,2])` should raise `TypeError`, too, right?

Comment: @Tim: for now i use this snippet only with 0 and 1, yes. but if it's easy to control any solutions will be appreciated

Comment: I'm only asking what should happen if the input were to contain anything besides 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def allOneOf(items, ids):
    first = items[0]
    if first in ids and all(i==first for i in items):
        return first
    else:
        raise TypeError()

assert_all_zero_or_one = (lambda vector: allOneOf(vector, set([0,1])))
```

Comment: i signed this one as right answer because it's the more general. but i used Matrin Stone's because it's a smart one!

Answer (score 4):

I think your solution conveys your intent well. You could also do

```
def assert_all_zero_or_one(vector):
    if set(vector) not in ({0}, {1}): raise TypeError
    return vector[0]
```

so you build `set(vector)` only once, but I think yours is easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

How's this?

```
def assert_all_zero_or_one(vector):
    if all(v==1 for v in vector): return 1
    elif all(v==0 for v in vector): return 0
    else: raise TypeError
```

Reads quite nicely, I think.

If you prefer short and cryptic:

```
def assert_all_zero_or_one(vector):
    a, = set(vector)
    return a
```

Although that gives you a ValueError rather than a TypeError.

Comment: Your second version will return `2` on an input of `[2,2,2]`.

Comment: Ah, yes. Well spotted. Still viable if 0 and 1 are the only values that would occur.

Comment: The 2nd line of the 2nd version could be changed into 
`try : a, = set(vector)`
`except ValueError : raise TypeError`
to raise the 'good' error type

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this.

```
import functools
import operator

def assert_all_zero_or_one(vector):
    if ((functools.reduce(operator.__mul__,vector) == 1) or (functools.reduce(operator.__add__,vector) == 0)):
            return vector[0]
    else:   
        raise TypeError("Your vector should be homogenous")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def assert_all_zero_or_one(vector):
    if len(vector) == sum(vector):
        return True
    elif sum(vector) == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

This should work nicely.

Comment: I just realised that this wont work if the input is [-1,1] or [2,0], etc... but the set method you used in your question will be faster anyways.